# Android View: force onDraw() and wait till its done

Tags: android

I got a View and want to update it every time a new line object is stored in my lines array. This happens at drawLine(). Therefore drawYourselfe() should somehow force onDraw() and wait till its done. Here is a part of my code. Can anyone tell me how drawYourselfe() should look?

```
public class MyView extends View{

    private ArrayList<Line> lines;
    private Paint paint; //created in constructor

    protected void drawLine(float[] f)
    {
        if(f.length != 5)
        {

        } else {
            lines.add(new Line(f));
            Log.d("SuM","added Line");
            if(!bufferedDrawing) // in this example bufferedDrawing=false because i want to update the View on every new Line;
            {
                drawYourselfe();
            }

        }
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Log.d("SuM","onDraw");

        for(Line l : lines)
        {
            l.analysis(); //Logs fromX,toX,fromY,toY and color to console

            paint.setColor(l.getColor());
            canvas.drawLine(l.getFromX(),l.getFromY(),l.getToX(),l.getToY(), paint);

        } 

    }

    public void drawYourselfe()
    {
        //When this is called, onDraw should be called and the Thread should wait till its done;
    }

}
```

Edit: 
I better mention what I want to do and why just simply invalidate() doesnt work: In my MainActivity I call

```
myView.drawLine(line1);
myView.drawLine(line2);
myView.drawLine(line3);
//and so on...
```

and I want to see how these lines are drawn one after one.
When calling invalidate() in drawYourselfe() I only see all lines drawn but not one after one. I know that these tree lines are drawn so fast that I cant see them drawn one by one, but in the app Im doing it with thousand of lines.

Comment: Drawing is very much fast operation that you can't detect through human eyes... I think human eye can detect only 16 frames per second (I am not sure)...

Comment: Well, i implemented the towers of Hanoi graphically using this which are really a long taking process till they are sloved, depending on the count of my plates. I allways just see them sloved after 20 sec or so but not how these plates ar moved.

Answer (score 1):

Call invalidate(), but there is no way to wait for the draw to complete. draw will be called later, after your drawLine call returns.

Answer (score 0):

Please call invalidate() function when add a new line. 
invalidate will call onDraw function

Comment: theoretical yes, but it dont work for me. As i understand invalidate just add a request to UIThread to get an update. This means that its not updated imideatly. When I add more lines in the time the view isnt updated android decide to skip frames or something like that. For result i dont get a kind of animation in which the drawing of new lines can be seen but only the final picture with all lines drawn.

Answer (score 0):

call `View.invalidate()` to force the `View` to redraw it's contents and as there is only one `Thread` here, it will wait until drawing is completed i.e. next instruction will not be executed until `onDraw()` is completed...

Comment: Wrong. From doc: Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) *will be called at some point in the future*.